# setState triggers constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since a couple of weeks or so I'm working on some tutorials to learn myself some React.

Now I'm trying to get Auth working with a admin dashboard. 
I have a sidebar in the dashboard and want it to toggle. This worked before I added Auth. 
Now I have a HOC as such:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({component: ComposedComponent, ...rest}) => {

  class Authentication extends Component {

    // redirect if not authenticated; otherwise, return the component inputted into <PrivateRoute />
    handleRender(props) {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        return <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
        }}/>;
      } else {
        return <ComposedComponent {...props}/>;
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <Route {...rest} render={this.handleRender.bind(this)}/>
      );
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authenticated: state.auth.authenticated};
  }

  const AuthenticationContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
  return <AuthenticationContainer/>;
};
```

And my TemplateComponent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Template.css';

class Template extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {toggled: true}
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({toggled: !this.state.toggled});
  };

  render() {
    const sidebar = `sidebar-toggle ${this.state.toggled ? 'active' : ''}`;
    return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" className="navbar-toggle" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="icon-bar"/>
                <span className="icon-bar"/>
                <span className="icon-bar"/>
              </a>
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="home.xhtml">
                Araido
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper" className={sidebar} >
              <ul className="sidebar-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#item2">Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#item3">Item 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default Template;
```

What happens now is when my component uses setState() it will trigger the constructor again. which sets my sidebar state back to toggled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Constructor function only loaded before the component mounting happen. setState shouldn't cause to trigger the constructor again.

Answer (score 0):

HOC is described as

> a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and
>   returns a new component.

source: [*Higher-Order Components - React Documentation*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method)

Your HOC instantiate a react component instead of just returning it. I'd say that more common pattern is to just return a new component instead of creating new instance immediately in HOC.

It can be a potential issue but it doesn't have to because it depends on how you use composed component by your HOC.

Still you can try and change this line

```
return <AuthenticationContainer/>;
// which is equal to
return React.createElement(AuthenticationContainer, null);
```

to

```
return AuthenticationContainer;
```

Bear in mind that it may not solve your problem. You shared only a small part of your application code but I'm sure for 100% that you struggle with issue described in official React documentation - [Don't Use HOCs Inside the render Method](http://tohttps://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method):

> [...] remounting a component causes the state of that component and
>   all of its children to be lost.

You have to find where your HOC is used in a wrong way. Look at the example which shows this issue: [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/QWEVANo77).

Click on `Toggle` button and open the console, you will see that with every `setState()` call in the parent component, `FooWithHello` is remounted and its constructor is called.

---

**Additional improvement #1**

Avoid creating new functions in render method so instead of using `.bind()` in `render()`:

```
<Route {...rest} render={this.handleRender.bind(this)}/>
```

you should do

```
this.handleRender = () => {
  if (!this.props.authenticated) {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />;
  }

  return <ComposedComponent {...props} />;
};

render() {
  return <Route {...rest} render={this.handleRender} />;
}
```

---

**Additional improvement #2**

when you want use previous state to build next state, you should use callback form of `setState()` like:

```
toggleMenu = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    toggled: !prevState.toggled,
  });
};
```